# How to strip insignificant whitespace out of HTML

Tags: java, html, whitespace

I have to compare different versions of HTML pages for formatting and text changes. Unfortunately the guy/company who creates them uses some kind of HTML editor that re-wraps all the HTML every time (and adds tons of whitespace), which makes it hard to diff them. So I am looking for a tool (preferrably a Java library) that can reformat my HTML in a way that all insignificant spaces and newlines get removed.

That means, in

```
<h1>First Headline</h1> <h2>Second headline</h2>
```

the space between `</h1>` and `<h2>` should be removed, but in

```
<b>formatted</b> <i>text</i>
```

the whitespace may not be removed. I do not care about `<pre>`, `<textarea>` or `<script>` blocks, and also not about CSS whitespace attributes that can change the behavior - I am just looking for a solution that strips most of the unnecessary whitespace (and better leave too much whitespace in than too little).

(I am already collapsing multiple whitespaces and re-adding newlines instead of whitespaces before tags to make the text more readable - but there are still too many cases where for example a new newline between headlines or table cells/rows breaks my simple "solution".)

Comment: Is it DOM-compliant clean HTML? You have more options in that case.

Comment: it is far from compliant. No idea which (wysiwyg) tool was used to create and edit the files, but the HTML is horrible (multiple head/body tags, lots of missing </tr> and </td> etc.).

Comment: and don't forget stuff like <b>th</b><i></i><b>is</b>...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) may be of use here. It's an HTML parser that parses the HTML (and is tolerant of ill-formed HTML) and presents the HTML as a DOM, and you can override the writing out of this to remove whatever you're not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for internal use only, then consider using a converter to XHTML, and then canonicalize the XML.  Then it is much easier to compare the results.

Tidy:  http://tidy.sourceforge.net/  (output-xhtml option - http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#output-xhtml)

Canonicalize: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML