# Java Program or Perl Script to copy text off a webpage

Tags: java, perl, web-scraping, copy-paste

Specifically im wondering if in java (preferred) or perl is it possible to enter a url and have it copy text from that page? Specifically I want to be able to search something on google and just copy paste the first 5 links that come up. Not doing SEO or anything its just for a program im working on.

Comment: This sort of scraping is forbidden by Google's terms of usage. Use the [API](http://code.google.com/more/#google-search) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can definitely be done in either language. Take a look at the following for java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

From the documentation:

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
    oracle.openStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(inputLine);

in.close();
```

This will give you the HTML on the page. You will need to parse that as needed to pull out the specific text you are interested in.

Comment: oh wow, so this would just give you the entire HTML as one stirng? amazing, would it remove whitespace?

Comment: This code example would print out the HTML but you could easily change it to concatenate the html into a string. Getting rid of whitespace is a bit trickier. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963337/how-to-strip-insignificant-whitespace-out-of-html

Comment: Any idea if this would work with a google search? I just tried to view the source code of a google search and no links are actually in the HTML im assuming all via PHP. might have to use some sort of image scanner to look and convert all the green links to text =/. Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 5):

not sure on Java (I'm sure it's possible) but for Perl you can try the CPAN module LWP/UserAgent can grab pages easily

http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.03/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');

if ($response->is_success) {
 print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
```

Seen your comment above, so thought I'd add. Stripping whitespace in Perl is easy:

```
$string =~ s/\s//g;
```

or applied to the above code

```
$response->decoded_content =~ s/\s//g;
```